# Split String array into columns java

Tags: java, html, arrays, string

I am trying to split this string of array delimited by dash/hyphen into columns but unable to do so. This code displays my split'd string correctly into rows but i would like to display in cols.

For e.g.

Input strings (separated by hyphen/dash as delimited):

```
Server Name 1 - id# 123
Server Name 2 - id# 234
```

Current o/p

```
Server Name 1
id# 123

Server Name 2
id# 234
```

Expected O/p:

```
Server Name 1 id# 123
Server Name 2 id# 234
```

Code:

```
for (String s : returns) {
    String[] s2=s.split("-");
    for(String results : s2) {
        out.append("<DIV>"+results+"</DIV>");
    }       
}
```

Comment: User `<p>` instead. `<div>` is block element.

Comment: so you just want to remove "-" from the string and thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each retrieved token is written in a HTML `div` :

```
for(String results : s2){
      out.append("<DIV>"+results+"</DIV>");
}
```

But `<div>` is a block-level element.
A block-level element always starts on a new line.
So you should group values of each line (for example `Server Name 1 id# 123`) in a same `<div>`.

For example :

```
for (String s : returns) {
     String[] s2=s.split("-");
     out.append("<DIV>");
     for(String results : s2){
        out.append(results);
        out.append("&nbsp;");
     } 
     out.append("</DIV>");
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please check you didn't forget something because you should not have this error.

Comment: one more help, can i get it displayed in table format in html so that i can sort the column headers?

Comment: I am not sure to give you a good advise as it is not my speciality. I encourage you to post a new question about it by specifying also the HTML tag .

Answer (score 0):

If you need a table in `Html` with columns as you say, You shouldn't use `<div>` because div element is block-displayed which means it will be displayed as a new line. what you need, is a table with `<tr>` as rows and `<td>` as your columns. Or you may use `<p>` (paragraph tag) or `<span>` tag. These tags are shown as in one line. then after one row you should use some tag for new line (like `<tr>` in `<table>` or `<br>` if you're not using `<table>`.
by the way, this question has very little relation with java! I guess it should be marked as an `HTML` question ;)